# Trigger to count total no of contacts in an account

Tags: trigger

```
trigger ContactFamilyCount on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete ){ 

        ContactFamilyCount.after_insert(trigger.new);

    }

}
```

---

```
public class ContactFamilyCount{
    public static void after_insert(List<Contact> conlist){ 

        Set<id> setOfAccIds = new Set<id>();    
        for(Contact con : conlist){

                setOfAccIds.add(con.AccountId);

        }
        List<Contact> contToRollup = new List<Contact>();
        Map<Id, Integer> countMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();        
        for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) ContactCount 
                                   FROM Contact 
                                   WHERE AccountId in: setOfAccIds
                                   GROUP BY AccountId]){
                                        //   countMap.put((Id) ar.get('AcctId'), (Integer) ar.get('ContactCount'));

                                           //Contact c = new Contact();
                                           system.debug((Integer) ar.get('ContactCount') +'contactcountttt');
                                          system.debug((Id) ar.get('AcctId') +'iddddddddddddd');
                                          // c.AccountId = (Id) ar.get('AcctId'); 
                                           //ar.TotalFamilyMember__c=
                                           contToRollup.add(new Contact(Id = (Id)ar.get('Id'),TotalFamilyMember__c= (Integer) ar.get('ContactCount') ));
                                          // c.TotalFamilyMember__c = (Integer) ar.get('ContactCount');
                                           //contToRollup.add(c);
                                           system.debug(contToRollup + 'listttttttt');

                                   }
        if(contToRollup.size()>0){
           update contToRollup;
        }

    }
    public static void after_update(List<Contact> conlist){ 

         Set<id> setOfAccIds = new Set<id>();    
        for(Contact con : conlist){

                setOfAccIds.add(con.AccountId);

        }
        List<Contact> contToRollup = new List<Contact>();

        for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) ContactCount 
                                   FROM Contact 
                                   WHERE AccountId in: setOfAccIds
                                   GROUP BY AccountId]){

                                           Contact c = new Contact();
                                           system.debug((Integer) ar.get('ContactCount') +'contactcountttt');
                                           system.debug((Id) ar.get('AcctId') +'iddddddddddddd');
                                           c.AccountId = (Id) ar.get('AcctId'); 


                                           c.TotalFamilyMember__c = (Integer) ar.get('ContactCount');
                                           contToRollup.add(c);
                                       }

        if(contToRollup.size()>0){
            update contToRollup;
        }

    }

}
}
```

---

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []: Class.ContactFamilyCount.after_insert: line 30, column 1

Comment: I strongly recommend you just declaratively build the trigger you need using **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**.

Comment: sir I don't have used   Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries. Is there any other alternatives

Comment: It's about as self explanatory as it could possibly be. Try installing it in a sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems with your code. The immediate error is caused because you don't specify a Contact Id for the record to update (lines 44-61, according to my text editor). More importantly, I suspect that you may have made an error in judgement; to summarize the *account* total, you'd want to have a field on the *account*. So, at the most simple level, this change should work:

```
    for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) ContactCount 
                               FROM Contact 
                               WHERE AccountId in: setOfAccIds
                               GROUP BY AccountId]){
        acctToRollup.add(new Account(id=(Id)ar.get('AcctId'), TotalFamilyMember__c = (Integer) ar.get('ContactCount')));
    }
    update acctToRollup;
}
```

However, this code ignores a small, but important detail; it won't work if you delete the last contact on the account, because the AggregateResult won't show zero-count values.

To fix that problem, you need a Map. Also, you should be checking both Trigger.old and Trigger.new, if available, in order to make sure that you don't miss updates where the account changes, and on deletion.

Overall, the method that would do the heavy lifting would look like this:

```
public static void rollupContacts(Contact[] oldList, Contact[] newList) {
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    if(newList != null) {
        for(Contact record: newList) {
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, TotalFamilyMember__c=0));
        }
    }
    if(oldList != null) {
        for(Contact record: oldList) {
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, TotalFamilyMember__c=0));
        }
    }
    // Ignore contacts without an account
    accounts.remove(null);
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT AccountId acctId, COUNT(Id) contactCount 
                                 FROM   Contact 
                                 WHERE  AccountId = :accounts.keySet()
                                 GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        accounts.get((Id)result.get('acctId')).TotalFamilyMember__c=(Decimal)result.get('contactCount');
    }
    update accounts.values();
}
```

Note that this is still not a complete solution; if you have validation rules or other logic that may block an update, you need to handle errors appropriately.

Because of the complexity of how things work, I strongly advise that you simply use [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which provides a nice graphical interface for you to work with, and takes care of all the nuances of writing robust rollup code for you.

Comment: No sir my requirement is to have field on contact

Comment: @ANISHKUMAR So create a formula from the Account. It doesn't make sense to update every contact on the account, recursively, just to know how many contacts are on the account. It's likely that whoever wrote your "requirement" was not clear enough, or doesn't understand what they're asking.

Comment: Is there not any alternative way to implement using coding

Comment: @ANISHKUMAR You can try this in Process Builder, but it will be painfully slow and limited. Code is the only efficient way to do this, and DLRS is the easiest way to accomplish that task.

Comment: Sir actually I have to accomplish it by using coding without using DLRS

Answer (score 0):

First create a trigger on Contact - Note that there should only be one trigger per object.

```
 trigger contactTrigger on Contact(before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    ContactTriggerHandler handler = new ContactTriggerHandler();   

    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
        //handler.BeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
    }
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.AfterInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
        //handler.BeforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap); 
    }     
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        //handler.AfterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap); 
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore){
        //handler.BeforeDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.AfterDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
    if(Trigger.isUndelete && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.AfterUndelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

Next create methods in your handler to filter the appropriate records to have the actions applied.

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {

    public void AfterInsert(List<Contact> newList, Map<Id, Contact> newMap){
        induceContactCountRecalculation(newList);
    }

    public void AfterDelete(List<Contact> oldList, Map<Id, Contact> oldMap){
        induceContactCountRecalculation(oldList);
    }

    public void AfterUndelete(List<Contact> oldList, Map<Id, Contact> oldMap){
        induceContactCountRecalculation(oldList);
    }

    private void induceContactCountRecalculation(List<Contact> myContacts){
        Set<Id> AccountIDs = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact c : myContacts){
            if(c.AccountId != null){
                AccountIDs.add(c.AccountId);
            }
        }
        if(!AccountIDs.isEmpty()){
            AccountService.CalculateContactCount(AccountIDs);
        }
    }
```

Finally create an AccountService class to perform account based actions such as recalculating the count of contacts.

```
 public class AccountService(){

        public static void CalculateContactCount(Set<Id> accountIds){
            if(accountIds.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }
            List<Account> accountsWithContactCounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT id FROM Contacts__r) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
            for(Account a : accountsWithContactCounts){
                a.TotalFamilyMember__c = a.contacts__r.size();
            }
            update accountsWithContactCounts;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir I have to populate the fields on contact not account

Comment: I would still do what I have mentioned above, then add a formula field on contact to look up to the account and fetch the value from that field.

Comment: Can't we do this just writing codes

Comment: In terms of relational database design, the aggregate sum of number of child records should belong on the parent, not the children. I still say that the total number belongs on the account with a formula field to refer to it on contact.